# no access token or session initiated when passing user through $facebook->getLoginUrl();

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, codeigniter-2

I have run the php sdk example from Facebook and it runs fine on my server but when I dropped the code into a method of codeigniters controller it doesn't return a session at all - has anyone experienced this?

Even thought it has been authenticated and the user has accepted the application I failed to get a session back- the only thing that is in the session is

```
[fb_32567534414789_state] => 3d34472df552ad7fef1911d2f97122f0
```

Even the url parameters are being passed back from Facebook - both state and code have values.

The problem is that it runs fine and without issue in a standalone example but when I bring it into controller method it doesnt work.

I have commented out every line in my controllers constructor and its method. Then only listing the example code with a model method to pull the api key/secret from the db; And it doesn't work;

I recently upgraded to the latest sdk - I'm stuck and do not know what to do.

**update**

i have added two examples to my server to show how its operating

this is the standard sdk example in a controller method of a brand new codeigniter install  (with the latest sdk pulled from github)

https://beta.exceleratedsolutions.com/testfb/welcome/testfb/

this is the standard sdk example

https://beta.exceleratedsolutions.com/testfb/examples/example.php

**code listing**

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * CodeIgniter
 *
 * An open source application development framework for PHP 5.1.6 or newer
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 * 
 * Licensed under the Academic Free License version 3.0
 * 
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0) that is
 * bundled with this package in the files license_afl.txt / license_afl.rst.
 * It is also available through the world wide web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/AFL-3.0
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to obtain it
 * through the world wide web, please send an email to
 * licensing@ellislab.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @author      EllisLab Dev Team
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2008 - 2012, EllisLab, Inc. (http://ellislab.com/)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/AFL-3.0 Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com
 * @since       Version 1.0
 * @filesource
 */

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -  
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in 
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }

    public function testfb(){

        $this->load->helper('facebook');

        // Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => '325675344144789',
          'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
        ));

        // Get User ID
        $user = $facebook->getUser();

        // We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
        //
        // If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
        // Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
        // token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

        if ($user) {
          try {
            // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
          } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $user = null;
          }
        }

        // Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
        if ($user) {
          $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
        } else {
          $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
        }

        // This call will always work since we are fetching public data.
        $naitik = $facebook->api('/naitik');

        ?>
        <!doctype html>
        <html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
          <head>
            <title>php-sdk</title>
            <style>
              body {
                font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
              }
              h1 a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #3b5998;
              }
              h1 a:hover {
                text-decoration: underline;
              }
            </style>
          </head>
          <body>
            <h1>php-sdk</h1>

            <?php if ($user): ?>
              <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
            <?php else: ?>
              <div>
                Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
                <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
              </div>
            <?php endif ?>

            <h3>PHP Session</h3>
            <pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

            <?php if ($user): ?>
              <h3>You</h3>
              <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">

              <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
              <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
            <?php else: ?>
              <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
            <?php endif ?>

            <h3>Public profile of Naitik</h3>
            <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/naitik/picture">
            <?php echo $naitik['name']; ?>
          </body>
        </html>

        <?php
    }
}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */
?>
```

as you see- this is just standard

**i have pushed this to pagodabox with the same issue**

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you have initiated a session elsewhere in your code if you are using session management of some kind.

Answer (score -1):

You could try put the Facebook php-sdk into library folder instead of helper. Also, you might follow this tutorial, it worked for me, maybe you're not setting some needed configurations (steps 1 to 5), also check the end of the tutorial for May 3rd Update:

http://www.dannyherran.com/2011/02/facebook-php-sdk-and-codeigniter-for-basic-user-authentication/

Regards

Comment: if its running on the same server it doesnt explain how codeigntier fails with it